# Cisco ASA - Delete or rename "names"

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall

I had a bad experience with Cisco ASA when changing/renaming "nameif" interface attributes.

I would like to know if renaming or simply deleting existing names used in ASA config will do any damage to the configuration.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I would like to know if renaming or simply deleting existing names used in ASA config will do any damage to the configuration.

You can safely delete and add `name` aliases because the ASA reverts to the IP address when the name disappears...

The original alias is `Xbox`...

```
asa5505(config)# sh runn | i Xbox
name 172.16.1.20 Xbox description Xbox
access-list INSIDE_in extended permit udp host Xbox any eq domain
access-list INSIDE_in extended permit tcp host Xbox any eq domain
access-list INSIDE_in extended permit udp host Xbox any eq 3074
access-list INSIDE_in extended permit tcp host Xbox any eq 3074
access-list INSIDE_in extended permit udp host Xbox any eq 88
```

Now deleting `Xbox`

```
asa5505(config)# no name 172.16.1.20 Xbox
asa5505(config)# sh runn | i 172.16.1.20
access-list INSIDE_in extended permit udp host 172.16.1.20 any eq domain
access-list INSIDE_in extended permit tcp host 172.16.1.20 any eq domain
access-list INSIDE_in extended permit udp host 172.16.1.20 any eq 3074
access-list INSIDE_in extended permit tcp host 172.16.1.20 any eq 3074
access-list INSIDE_in extended permit udp host 172.16.1.20 any eq 88
asa5505(config)#
```

And adding `Xbox-new` on the same address...

```
asa5505(config)# name 172.16.1.20 XBox-new descr temporary example
asa5505(config)# sh runn | i 172.16.1.20
name 172.16.1.20 XBox-new description temporary example
asa5505(config)# sh runn | i XBox
name 172.16.1.20 XBox-new description temporary example
access-list INSIDE_in extended permit udp host XBox-new any eq domain
access-list INSIDE_in extended permit tcp host XBox-new any eq domain
access-list INSIDE_in extended permit udp host XBox-new any eq 3074
access-list INSIDE_in extended permit tcp host XBox-new any eq 3074
access-list INSIDE_in extended permit udp host XBox-new any eq 88
asa5505(config)#
```

**Bonus material: renaming a `nameif`**

> I had a bad experience with Cisco ASA when changing/renaming "nameif" interface attributes.

Renaming `nameif` on an interface works just fine in ASA 8.2(5)... This is an example of changing `nameif OUTSIDE` to `nameif newOUTSIDE`

```
asa5505# sh nameif
Interface                Name                     Security
Vlan100                  OUTSIDE                    0
Vlan200                  INSIDE                   100
asa5505# sh runn | i access-group
access-group OUTSIDE_in in interface OUTSIDE
access-group INSIDE_in in interface INSIDE
asa5505# conf t
asa5505(config)# int vlan100
asa5505(config-if)# nameif newOUTSIDE
asa5505(config-if)# show nameif
Interface                Name                     Security
Vlan100                  newOUTSIDE                 0
Vlan200                  INSIDE                   100
asa5505(config-if)# sh runn | i newOUTSIDE
 nameif newOUTSIDE
mtu newOUTSIDE 1500
global (newOUTSIDE) 1 interface
access-group OUTSIDE_in in interface newOUTSIDE
ssl trust-point LOCAL_CERT_gw_200904 newOUTSIDE
asa5505(config-if)#
```

The ASA even renamed the interface references from `OUTSIDE` to `newOUTSIDE` automatically... TCP sessions through the FW did not drop when I did it.

*WARNING*

Whatever you do, do *not* try `no nameif <something here>`... it will hose your config...

```
asa5505(config)# int vlan100
asa5505(config-if)# no nameif OUTSIDE
asa5505(config-if)# nameif newBrokenOUTSIDE
```

Comment: Thank you, good to know it. Still I am concern about deleting the names.

E.g. names
name 10.16.146.10 FTP-Server

Comment: One little question: do you happen to know since when this feature was added? I run 8.0.4 on the present device.

Comment: According to the [ASA 8.0 nameif docs](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa80/command/reference/no.html#wp1747183), it works in 8.0 too